# mosquitto ACL to restrict client

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have mosquitto with TLS working and want to add ACL to restrict client from reading/writing/creating topics.

All client to publish to `/device/registration` topic, Client should only subscribe to client specific topic `/device/certificate/<client_id>`, for this I have this in ACL file

*mosquitto.acl*

```
topic write /device/registration
pattern read /device/certificate/%c
```

How can I add backend process (`backend-app` client) to read/write to all these topics ?

Also completely bar all client from subscribing to topic `$SYS/#` and creating any other topics with any name ?

Comment: Edit the question to show your actual ACL file so we can see how you've added the sections you've mentioned. Order matters so we need to see them in context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the ACL file normally applies rules to specific users, with each users set of rules being dictated by a leading `user <username>` entry.

Any rules before the first `user <username>` entry are applied to any anonymous users (assuming `allow_anonymous true` is in the config file).

At the moment your rules apply to all anonymous users.

The easiest way to add a rule for the backend service is to have it sign in as a specific user and have an explicit rule to allow that user. e.g.

```
topic write /device/registration
pattern read /device/certificate/%c

user backend-app
pattern readwrite #
```

This will allow the `backend-app` user to both publish and subscribe to any topic. You can specify the user/passwords in the file set with the `password_file` setting. (But if you are going to be adding users/devices dynamically it might be better to look at using the `auth_plugin` settings to access the ACL/User/Password details from a database that can be easily updated.)

User/password for device authorisation is better than just using client_id's because there is nothing to stop somebody from setting their client_id to that matching anybody elses.

Comment: ok, how can I bar client from creating any other topics ? and subscribing to `$SYS/#` topic ? except `backend-app` client

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything, if they don't have explicit read/write permission they won't be able to publish anything to that topic